# Flexbox: Buttons shifting when on hover with ::after element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox for my nav bar and one problem I have encountered is when I hover over one of the buttons, the rest shifted a little due to my `::after` element.

I tried setting a width for the `<a>` tag so the change of width on hover will only affect inside that width, but it didn't respond as I was hoping it to.

Can I get some suggestions on how to solve this?

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0 75px;
  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 715px;
    a {
      padding: 5px;
      &:hover::after {
        content: ".";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home">
    <h1>Brillian.</h1>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single dot, `position: absolute` will do fine without bothering the layout:

```css
a {
    padding: 5px;

    &:hover::after {
        content: ".";
        position: absolute;
    }
```

below snippet with plain CSS for testing:

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0 75px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 715px;
}

nav ul a {
  padding: 7px;
}

nav ul a:hover::after {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home">
    <h1>Brillian.</h1>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It's one way to tackle the problem I guess. 
Edit: I GOT IT WORKING!

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0 75px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
  list-style: none;
}
nav h1:hover::after {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute;
}
nav ul a:hover::after {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#home"><h1>Brillian.</h1></a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Ricky, it works! I was setting width to <a> instead of <li> before, I guess that explains why it wasn't working :D   Is there another way to get around writing out all the width for the buttons though? I mean  if there are 100 buttons, does that mean I'll have to measure one by one of their width?

Comment: Do you want all your buttons to have a set size? I considered giving that as an answer but it wouldn't look too pretty. You want the space between each button to be the same right?

Comment: Yes, i do want the buttons to be spacing in the same distance

Comment: ikr! But you're both amazing for solving this!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Good question though! +1, put the old noggin to work haha